# C# send file (pdf, html or rtf) to printer

Tags: c#

I have a problem with printing the files in C #. How to print any file with the possibility of two-sided printing.

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = @"c:\output.pdf";
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
            p.Kill();
```

But it does not satisfy me, because I can not here set the print parameters.  How can I do this using the `PrintDocument` class?

I using Spire PDF to convert pdf to image.

```
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
            pdf.LoadFromFile("e:\\proba1.pdf");

            BitmapSource source;
            Bitmap bmp;

            for (int i = 1; i < pdf.Pages.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                source = pdf.SaveAsImage(i);
                bmp = SourceToBitmap(source);
                bmp.Save(string.Format("result-{0}.png", i), ImageFormat.Png);
            }
```

But, I get a error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'    C:\Users\Łukasz\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs    90  26  FileMonitor
Error   2   The name 'SourceToBitmap' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Łukasz\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs    91  23  FileMonitor
Error   3   The name 'ImageFormat' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\Łukasz\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs    92  62  FileMonitor
```

Comment: What is wrong with the [MSDN Article on PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I want to print a file as it is, without setting fonts, etc.

Comment: `StreamReader` do not print the pdf file

Comment: I was looking for in such a way: c# print pdf file

Comment: c# print pdf file library -> on 3rd position (in my search result)

Comment: you did not follow the tutorial: see new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Free .NET PDF Library (free, on visualstudiogallery). Convert the PDF to Image and print this with PrintDocument ....

Comment: It is necessary to convert the image?

Comment: If you want to print it by your code YES, if you use the Fox IT Lib you an print it direct (but you would need to pay ...)

Comment: Okay, take advantage of the free version - Free .NET PDF Library. So I need to convert the image and it just printed using functions available in c # so?

Comment: And for the conversion of use of the above libraries?

Comment: of course you must be aware of multipage pdf documents, so you have to print each page. you find the details about printing from c# in the article mentioned by @PatrikEckebrecht

Comment: You should take a closer look to the library: There is a way to "open" the pdf, "enumerate" pages, "extract" page as Image -> and then standard functions to print (although you need to write some code, it´s not only "print Image", but you find this in the MSDN).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82815/discussion-between-thomas-krojer-and-lukassz).

Comment: Are there any other free sdk?

Answer (score 0):

For Spire.NET (from tutorial)

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(); 
doc.LoadFromFile("sample.pdf"); 
Bitmap bmp = doc.SaveAsImage(0); 
bmp.Save("convertToBmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```